# HTML component for XML editing

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml

I apply html HTML page to edit and send xml on the server.
To make it more useful I would like to have HTML based decision with following properties:

1. Highlight XML syntax during editing (required);
2. Lightweight in size (e.g. 5+ Mb is too much) (required)
3. Validate XML on-the-fly or by request (e.g. by button press) (optional)
4. Be free (is pretty required, but I'm open for paid decision if it really covers all requirements);

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may wish to check out [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/), which has XML syntax highlighting, autocomplete, tag closing, and some other great features.

I'm not certain that CodeMirror includes XML validation per se, but it shouldn't be very difficult to add if you can just use an XmlHttpRequest to send the content to an online XML validation service of some sort.

Comment: That's not entirely true.  CodeMirror has an [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/codemirror), but can also work by just loading it from a [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/codemirror) or manually uploading the binary.

Comment: Ahh didn't realise this when i was trying to get it to work yesterday. In the end I opted for a more lightweight editor - CodeFlask